# Unable to run Tor in Kali as root

Tags: kali-linux, tor

I recently installed Kali linux (32bit) on my system. I downloaded the tor browser bundle and when I ran it, it displayed-

```
The Tor Browser Bundle should not be run as root
```

So as mentioned in one of the questions on the network, I edited the `start-tor-browser`  file, and commented out the `exit 1`  part. Now when I run Tor, it displays the following error message repeatedly- 
[image: Tor error log]

Clicking restart Tor doesnt help. Although , when I ran tor after creating a non root account, it ran without any glitch. So, how should I get tor running in root ?

Comment: See http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/the-tor-browser-bundle-should-not-be-run-as-root-why

Comment: You should not login as root, and much less ran a graphical interface or any kind of browser as root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tor` performs many checks before starting, stopping if something in your system is deemed insecure. For example, wrong owner or bad permissions on `torrc` file could be the cause. A similar check is performed on `tor` executable itself.

You should run `tor` in a terminal, and check its output for errors. They are quite verbose and easy to understand. Fix those errors and `tor` will run.

If you can't be bothered with reading error messages, you can try to navigate to the directory where `tor` resides and execute the following command as `root`:

```
chown -R root *
```

Pay attention when executing this command, it may wreck your system if executed in the wrong directory.

Answer (score 0):

Find the TOR Browser Install file and open with a text editor.  It's a larger file in BASH-script so be patient.  Find the if/ /fi command that includes

```
if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
complain "The Tor Browser Bundle should not be run as root.  Exiting."
exit 1
fi
```

The just delete Everything between the 'if..and..fi'. Save and install/ run as 
root.

Update:  this is a dangerous move, especially running a browser with su evelation.